# Check worker name that triggers a particular Job id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project. I'm wondering if I can get the worker name that triggered the particular job using the job id so I can display the appropriate message after it is done. Is this possible? or should I just save the worker name in the model?

```py
#I have a method that creates the job

def generate

   my_model.job_id = HardWorker.perform_async()
   my_model.save!
end

def check_status
   if job_id && Sidekiq::Status::complete?(my_model.job_id)
      # if HardWorker
      #    "HardWorker is done!"
      # elseif AnotherWorker
      #    "AnotherWorker is Done!"
      # end
   end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to get Worker Class using job id:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new
job = queue.detect { |job| job.jid == job_id //<-- the job id you have from perfrom_async }
```

Your code would be something like this:

```
def check_status
  queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new
  job = queue.detect { |job| job.jid == my_model.job_id }

  if job_id && Sidekiq::Status::complete?(my_model.job_id)
    puts "#{job.klass} is done" <-- The worker that triggered the job
  end
end
```

More on queues [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#queue)

Comment: Can you explain why, I've tested it

Comment: Once a job is executing, it's not enqueued anymore. You tested a scenario that never happens in the real world.  Once a worker pulls that job, your code wouldn't find it.